# Htaccess file work only in a project

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using the same code, but it work only on first project.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?pg=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: What is working on the **first**? Can you be more specific about this problem?

Comment: sorry! I forgot. I have two projects, and i use the same code htaccess for two, i am using xampp. but the htaccess code work just in one project